# HttpError 400 in jobs.get(jobId,ProjectId) even with right values

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

when I call jobs.get(jobId,ProjectID);
I get:

> "code" : 400,   "errors" : [ {
>   "domain" : "global",
>   "message" : "Invalid project ID 'My_Project_ID:job_6c2e8cc358ad42d2ad55ef266d342b68'. 
>   Project IDs must contain 6-63 lowercase letters, digits, or dashes. IDs must start with
>   a letter and may not end with a dash.",
>   "reason" : "invalid"   } ],   "message" : "Invalid project ID 'My_Project_ID:job_6c2e8cc358ad42d2ad55ef266d342b68'. Project IDs must
>   contain 6-63 lowercase letters, digits, or dashes. IDs must start with
>   a letter and may not end with a dash."

(I switched projectId with "My_Project_ID")

If I use the exact projectID and jobID in the "try it" section in the google developer guide
in [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get)

I get the job back as expected!

If projectId or jobId wasn't right then it wouldn't have worked in the google developer site also.
What can cause this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're passing the fully-qualified job ID as the project ID.  In the example you mentioned above, "My_Project_ID" is the project ID and "job_6c2e8cc358ad42d2ad55ef266d342b68" is the job ID, but it looks like you're passing the full string "My_Project_ID:job_6c2e8cc358ad42d2ad55ef266d342b68" as the job ID.

Note also that the parameter order is (projectId, jobId), not (jobId, projectId).

Try calling jobs.get("My_Project_ID", "job_6c2e8cc358ad42d2ad55ef266d342b68"), and see if that works.

Comment: I tried switching jobId and ProjectID , still didn't work, Error message change a bit and now its talking about JobID but the combined string ProjectId+JobId remain the same

Comment: {
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid job ID \"My_Project_ID:job_894b0d528b0748b6b5cd68d0363a2a2a\". Job IDs must be alphanumeric (plus underscores and dashes) and must be at most 1024 characters long.",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid job ID \"My_Project_ID:job_894b0d528b0748b6b5cd68d0363a2a2a\". Job IDs must be alphanumeric (plus underscores and dashes) and must be at most 1024 characters long."
}

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when trying to do following:

jobs().get(projectId, job.getId()).execute().getStatus().getState();

Seems like job.getId() returns a String which contains both ProjectId and JobId (and contains characters which are not allowed in Job-Ids).
The solution is to call job.getJobReference().getJobId() instead.

jobs().get(projectId, job.getJobReference().getJobId()).execute().getStatus().getState();